# Mailchimp API 2.0 and Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, mailchimp

I need to use the Mailchimp API v2 from an iOS App. I see that there is not an Objective-C wrapper at the moment and I'm bit confused.

I can't understand how to proceed to use the API from iOS. I know how to create Mailchimp keys and how to setup my list, I need to understand how to perform calls from the Phone to the MailChimp server.

**Here my doubts:**

- If I perform a simple HTTP call from the device, users could spoof data and "steal" my key and access every email in the list (Am I wrong?)
- I can't understand if there is an authentication process to perform before sending the http request. The documentation doesn't speak about oAuth to be able to use the API.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of ChimpKit for iOS, [ChimpKit3](https://github.com/mailchimp/ChimpKit3) is an Objective-C wrapper for MailChimp API 2.0. It supports OAuth2 as well.

Here is the OAuth2 documentation of Mailchimp API: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/oauth2/